# Vertically aligning a div inside a div that has a percentage height and width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to vertically align a div inside a div (to make a play button for a video) and i've tried all the traditional methods of vertically aligning, and have even tried a jquery script to vertically align it, but as of yet i'm still to no avail.

EDIT - The content / The circle play button needs to be fully responsive so i can't remove the 20% width and the 20% padding-bottom it has.

A live version of the website can be found here - 
http://www.mosesmartin.co.uk/digitalguys/gkn.php
and the div in question is 'videoplay' div

HTML

```
<div class="rectanglewrap">
    <div class="rectangleimg" id="gknengine">
        <div class="videoplay vcenter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" id="playbutton"></span></div>
    </div>              
</div>
```

CSS

```
.rectangleimg{
  position:relative;
  height:0;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom:50%;
}
.div-centerer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.vcenter {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.videoplay {
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #12A537;
  height:0;
  width:20%;
  padding-bottom:20%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Please help me, this is bugging the hell out of me!

Thankyou

Comment: try http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: I forgot to add, The circle play button needs to be fully responsive with no fixed sizes either so the table-cell method won't work (like howtocenterincss suggests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using relative and absolute positioning, you can use percentages to adapt to mobile like so:

```
.rectanglewrap {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}
.videoplay {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10%;
    width: 20%;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

The top & left margins should be half the width & height of the play element respectively (& they can be percentages).

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fs52w2L/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this wont work, the `height:0; width:20%; padding-bottom:20%;` inside video play can't be removed or altered. unless there's another way of making a fully responsive circle

Comment: So you can't add to the .videoplay class? It still mostly works even with the padding bottom, and width, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/7fs52w2L/3/

Comment: You're right! With a little adaptation the green button is now sitting nicely in the center of the div I had to change the 'top' setting to `top:30%` though. Thankyou very much!

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question jQuery, here's how to do it in jQuery:

```
$('#playbutton').css('top', ($('#gknengine .videoplay').outerHeight() / 2) - ($('#playbutton').height() / 2));
```

You'll probably want to put it in a `$(window).resize()` handler.

Comment: Thanks that's done half of what i need done, with that script it's vertically aligned the arrow part of the button (which also wouldn't vertically align for some reason). I need the green part centering inside the image too.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about [older browser](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) (eg IE < 9) you can use [transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) to center your div only with CSS

```
div.videoplay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  // margin-top: 1px <--- delete
}

#playbutton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  // top: 1px <--- delete
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was going to use that method as a last resort but it seems that someone's given me the solution now :)